# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null cant find an issue

Tags: javascript

I have to use vanilla JavaScript for a project of making a weather app. I keep getting the issue **"cannot read property of 'addEventListener' of null** . I have tried adding **window.onload(function)** before the code but i still get the same issue.

```
const api = {
    key: "",
    baseurl: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"
    }

const searchbox = document.querySelector('search-box');
searchbox.addEventListener('keypress', setQuery);


function setQuery(evt) {
    if(evt.keycode == 13) {
        getResults(searchbox.value);
        console.log(searchbox.value);
    }
}

function getResults(query) {
fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
    .then(weather => {
        return weather.json();

    }).then(displayResults);
}

function displayResults (weather) {
    let city = document.querySelector('.location .city');
    city.innerText = `${weather.name}, ${weather.sys.country}`;

    let now = new Date();
    let date = document.querySelector('.location .date');
    date.innerText = dateBuilder(now);

    let temp = document.querySelector('.current .temp');
    temp.innerHTML= `${Math.round(weather.main.temp)}<span>°C</span>`;

    let weather_el = document.querySelector('.current .weather');

    weather_el.innerText= weather.weather[0].main;

    let hilow= document.querySelector('.hi-low');
    hilow.innerText = `${weather.name}, ${weather.sys.country}°C / ${weather.main.temp_max}°C`;
}

function dateBuilder (d) {
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April",
    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"];
    let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    let day= days[d.getDay()];
    let date= d.getDate();
    let month = months[d.getMonth()];
    let year = d.GetFullYear();

    return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`;
}
```

```
searchbox.addEventListener('keypress', setQuery);
```

is null

Comment: You are missing hash symbol (or dot, if it's a className), it should be: `const searchbox = document.querySelector('#search-box');`

Comment: You may want to give to publishing your API keys on internet a second thought.

Comment: #1 oh didnt even notice thanks

Comment: "You are missing hash symbol (or dot, if it's a className), it should be: const searchbox = document.querySelector('#search-box'); – Samuli Hakoniemi 1 hour ago "  Tried this still having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Check your input in the html doc, it should have a class="search-box"  like this

Comment: Please use markup to make your answer more pretty and show a more detailed code block.